# Multiple SUM(CASE WHEN) causing cumulative sums

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to develop an SQL Server View for a report that includes the Base Bid price for a project (if selected), any potentially selected alternate bids (if selected), and any approved Change Orders. My SQL is as follows.

```
SELECT p.ProjectID,
    p.ProjectName,
    e.NAME AS PM,
    ps.Description AS STATUS,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN b.PriceBaseSelected = 1
                THEN b.PriceBase
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) AS BaseBid,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN ba.Selected = 1
                THEN ba.Amount
            ELSE 0
            END) AS 'AltBidSum',
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN pco.STATUS = 'A'
                THEN pco.Amount
            ELSE 0
            END) AS COSum
FROM tblProject AS p
INNER JOIN tblProjectStatus AS ps ON p.ProjectStatusID = ps.ProjectStatusID
INNER JOIN tblEmployee AS e ON p.Scope_PM_EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN tblBid AS b ON p.ProjectID = b.BidID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblBidAlternate AS ba ON p.ProjectID = ba.BidID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblProjectChangeOrder AS pco ON p.ProjectID = pco.ProjectID
WHERE ps.Description <> 'Complete'
    AND ps.Description <> 'Accounting'
GROUP BY p.ProjectID,
    p.ProjectName,
    ps.Description,
    e.NAME,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN b.PriceBaseSelected = 1
                THEN b.PriceBase
            ELSE 0
            END
        )
```

The problem I am running into is that with the left join on the tblProjectChangeOrder, when there are multiple change orders, the query is summing the alt bid sum for each change order. For example, if I have a selected Base Bid of $10,000, A single selected Alternate Bid of $2,000, and 4 approved Change Orders of $500 each, I should get an output of 10000, 2000, and 2000. What I am getting is an output of 10000, 8000, and 2000. There can be multiple alternate bids hence the need to sum the column.

I am guessing my problem stems from joining two different tables with a potentially different amount of sums in each. If I had two selected alternate bids, I can expect my change order sum to double. Is there a way to structure this so that I can have sums of two different tables irrespective of the number of alternates or change orders?

Comment: Use `sum(Insert SumColumnHere [ba.Amount or Pco.amount] depending) over partition by (P.projectID)` to eliminate the artificial inflation occurring by the 1:M records perhaps? or do the summing before the joins in a derrived table/inline view.